# How to specify / Add tags before the Nested XML on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, for-loop

I am trying to bypass C# to build a google shopping feed directly from SQL Server.
This is what I have for the nested XML body.

```
DECLARE @XMLBODY XML
SET @XMLBODY = (
SELECT 
           ID as "ID", 
           title as "title",
           link as "link",
           [description] as "description",
           image_link as "image_link"
          ,[Price] as "Price"
          ,[mpn] as "mpn"
          ,[brand] as "brand"
          ,[Condition] as "Condition"
          ,[availability] as "availability"
          ,[shipping_weight] as "shipping_weight"
          ,[google_product_category] as "google_product_category"
          ,[custom_label_0] as "custom_label_0"
          ,[custom_label_1] as "custom_label_1"
          ,[custom_label_2] as "custom_label_2"
          ,[custom_label_3] as "custom_label_3"
          ,[custom_label_4] as "custom_label_4" FROM dbo.SmartShoppingFeed
FOR XML PATH ('item'))
SELECT @XMLBODY
```

And as result, I am getting the following XML (only showing first 2..)

```
<item>
      <ID>22760</ID>
      <title>76101 - Product Name A</title>
      <link>landingpage2.aspx</link>
      <description>body spacers</description>
      <image_link>productimage_001.jpg</image_link>
      <Price>427.6300</Price>
      <mpn>76101AA</mpn>
</item>
<item>
      <ID>22760</ID>
      <title>76101 - Product Name B</title>
      <link>landingpage2.aspx</link>
      <description>body spacers</description>
      <image_link>productimage_002.jpg</image_link>
      <Price>427.6300</Price>
      <mpn>76102AA</mpn>
</item>
```

And what I need as final result is the body with schema, version, and NS before the body and closing tag after the body as follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
<channel>
<title>storename</title>
<link>https://www.storename.com/</link>
<description></description>
<language>en-US</language>
<pubDate>Thu, 25 Jul 2019 20:43:33 GMT</pubDate>
<lastBuildDate>Thu, 25 Jul 2019 20:43:33 GMT</lastBuildDate>
  <item>
      <ID>22760</ID>
      <title>76101 - Product Name A</title>
      <link>landingpage2.aspx</link>
      <description>body spacers</description>
      <image_link>productimage_001.jpg</image_link>
      <Price>427.6300</Price>
      <mpn>76101AA</mpn>
  </item>
  <item>
      <ID>22760</ID>
      <title>76101 - Product Name B</title>
      <link>landingpage2.aspx</link>
      <description>body spacers</description>
      <image_link>productimage_002.jpg</image_link>
      <Price>427.6300</Price>
      <mpn>76102AA</mpn>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

I have tried many workarounds to add them statically by casting as string and use concat to combine the head and tail with the body but that didn't work as planned.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use XQuery to easily re-shape the final XML as follows:

> SQL

```
DECLARE @XMLBODY XML = '<item>
      <ID>22760</ID>
      <title>76101 - Product Name A</title>
      <link>landingpage2.aspx</link>
      <description>body spacers</description>
      <image_link>productimage_001.jpg</image_link>
      <Price>427.6300</Price>
      <mpn>76101AA</mpn>
</item>
<item>
      <ID>22760</ID>
      <title>76101 - Product Name B</title>
      <link>landingpage2.aspx</link>
      <description>body spacers</description>
      <image_link>productimage_002.jpg</image_link>
      <Price>427.6300</Price>
      <mpn>76102AA</mpn>a
</item>';

DECLARE @finalXML XML;
SET @finalXML = @XMLBODY.query('<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
<channel>
<title>storename</title>
<link>https://www.storename.com/</link>
<description></description>
<language>en-US</language>
<pubDate>Thu, 25 Jul 2019 20:43:33 GMT</pubDate>
<lastBuildDate>Thu, 25 Jul 2019 20:43:33 GMT</lastBuildDate>
{
    for $item in /item
    return $item
}
  </channel>
</rss>
');
SELECT @finalXML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, Google product feed requires *prefixes* so the solution may look like this.

```
DECLARE @XMLBODY XML
with xmlnamespaces('http://base.google.com/ns/1.0' as g,
                   'http://base.google.com/cns/1.0' as c)
SELECT @XMLBODY = (
SELECT 
           ID as "g:ID", 
           title as "title",
           link as "link",
           [description] as "description",
           image_link as "g:image_link"
          ,[Price] as "g:price"
          ,[mpn] as "g:mpn"
          ,[brand] as "g:brand"
          ,[Condition] as "g:condition"
          ,[availability] as "g:availability"
          ,[shipping_weight] as "g:shipping_weight"
          ,[google_product_category] as "g:google_product_category"
          ,[custom_label_0] as "c:custom_label_0"
          ,[custom_label_1] as "c:custom_label_1"
FROM dbo.SmartShoppingFeed
FOR XML PATH ('item'),root('root'))
SELECT @XMLBODY
```

And then apply great @Yitzhak Khabinsky's solution.